# Regex array of number

Tags: regex

I have a problem with regex and need your help. I want to check my string is correct or incorrect. First and last is a number, only number and comma after it. No space inside 2 numbers.

Ex:

- 1,2,3,49,5 this is correct
- 1,2,3,45, this is incorrect
- ,12,4,2,67 this is incorrect
- 1,2 3,4,5,6 this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Please check below regex to solve your problem.

Regex: `^[0-9]+([0-9,])+[0-9]+$`

`^[0-9]+` is for start with one or more number

`[0-9]+$` is for end with one or more number

`([0-9,])+` is for one or more number with comma

Please check the output in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HmEgbp/1)

**Update:**

Please check the updated regex: `^(\d+,)+\d+$`

`^(\d+,)+` is for one or more number with comma and this will handle first number with comma

`\d+$` is for end with one or more number

Please check the updated output in [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/HmEgbp/2)

Comment: try 3+ digit number as an input. Your expression doesn't fail. But fails with 1 and 2 digit number.

Comment: Also matches "1,,,,,1". So..

Comment: Please check the updated solution.

Comment: the same Sedo's problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?:\d+,)*\d+$
```

`(?:\d+,)*` - gets matches like "0," "00," "000," ... or empty

`\d+` - gets last number as "0" "00" "000"

Comment: Works for single element array

Comment: thank you  so much, you are right.